# Laravel mass assigning guarded fields

Tags: laravel, mass-assignment

So basically, I'm using mass assignment for convenience. However I have a guarded field called "userid". I've made the separate code to insert into this field but for some reason I still get the error: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'userid' doesn't have a default value`

Code:

```
$apply = Apply::create(
        $request->all()
    );
    $apply->userid = Auth::user()->id;
    $apply->save();
    return redirect()->route('apply');
```

Model:

```
protected $guarded = ['userid'];
```

Thanks.

EDIT:
Still not fixed, any other solutions?

Comment: why is the field guarded ? ain't there a setter you've implemented ? a scope maybe ?

Comment: no? i haven't added it as a field so that's the only way to set it.. right?

Comment: Using `create` will attempt to store a record in the database. You've defined the `userid` column to not be null in your migration, so the call to `create` will fail as `$request->all()` does not contain `userid`.

Comment: Thanks, so how am I supposed to work around it?

Answer (score 0):

pass the userid field to the create function,

```
 $apply = Apply::create(array_merge(
         $request->all(),
         [
            "userid" => Auth::user()->id
         ])
         );

     $apply->save();

return redirect()->route('apply');
```

Comment: i did it with the edit and got `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'userid' doesn't have a default value`